# How does strcat affect the strtok?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c-strings, strtok, strcat

Assume we need to copy user's input into another string by concatenating the tokens of input, e.g., `"hello world" -> "helloworld"`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char buffer[50];

  printf("\nEnter a string: ");

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0) {
    size_t size = strlen(buffer);

    if (size > 0 && buffer[size - 1] == '\n') {
      char input[1]; // set it too small 
      buffer[size - 1] = '\0';

      char *tok = strtok(buffer, " "); // works fine
      do {
        strcat(input, tok); // append to "input" that has not enough space
        printf("\nfound token: %s", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " "); // produces garbage
      } while (tok);

     break;
  }
}
```

Running the code above:

```
Enter a string: hello world

found token: hello
found token: w
found token: r
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

I struggle to understand how is `strtok` related to `strcat` failing to append `tok`. They are not sharing variables except for `tok` which is (according to the docs) copied by `strcat`, so whatever `strcat` is doing shouldn't affect the `strtok` behavior and the program should crash on the second `strcat` call at least, right? But we see that `strcat` is getting called 3 times before stack smashing gets detected. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Undefined behavior (like writing into `input` more than it can hold) is undefined.

Comment: All bets are off as soon as you purposely overflow `input`. That results in Undefined Behaviour. "*so whatever strcat is doing shouldn't affect the strtok*". Why would you think that? Overflowing `input` could overwrite anything including `buffer` which could very well affect `strtok` on that `buffer`.

Comment: @DevSolar yes, but it persists from run to run, so technically it is a "defined" undefined behavior. I thought that undefined in C means random garbage each run.

Comment: No, *technically* it is undefined behavior, and even if that might be reproducable and explainable it still means your code is broken, and you have no right to expect reproducability. Whether it's random garbage, the same result each time, or your computer uploading your hard drive contents to cloud space. ;-) Which makes it rather moot to explain what happened *in this specific circumstance*, because it might differ with a different compiler version, standard library implementation, or moon phase.

Comment: `char input[1]; // set it too small`  You nailed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this array

```
char input[1];
```

is not initialized and does not contain a string.

So this call of strcat

```
strcat(input, tok);
```

invokes undefined behavior also because the array input is not large enough to store the copied string. It can overwrite memory beyond the array.

Comment: So could it be the case that the memory beyond the array contains `buffer` data and `strcat` just overwrites it?

Comment: @minerals It can override the variable tok  or buffer or all together.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `char input[1];` is too small to do anything. You cannot concatenate the tokens from the line into this minuscule array. You must define it with a sufficient length, namely the same length as `buffer` for simplicity.
- `input` must be initialized as an empty string for `strcat(input, tok);` to have defined behavior. As coded, the first call to `strcat` corrupts other variables causing the observed behavior, but be aware anything else could happen as a result of this undefined behavior.
- `char *tok = strtok(buffer, " ");` works fine but may return a null pointer if `buffer` contains only whitespace if anything. The `do` loop will then invoke undefined behavior on `strcat(input, tok)`. Use a `for` or `while` loop instead.
- there is a missing `}` in the code, it is unclear whether you mean to `break` from the `while` loop after the first iteration or only upon getting the end of the line.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[50];
    char input[sizeof buffer] = "";

    printf("Enter a string: ");

    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {
        char *tok = strtok(buffer, " \n");
        while (tok) {
            strcat(input, tok);
            printf("found token: %s\n", tok);
            tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        printf("token string: %s\n", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char input[1];` is on purpose, I was experimenting while reading a book. Thanks for pointing out the null pointer. Missing brace is just wrong edit after copy-paste.